# Set a form's action attribute when submitting?

Tags: html, forms, submit, action

How do I change a form's action attribute right after clicking the submit button?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Attach to the submit button `click` event and change the `action` attribute in the event handler.

Comment: @dave - can you also explain why you can't set the `action` attribute to the required value _before_ the submit?

Comment: thats what I'm trying to figure out tbh.

Comment: @dave - I mean when rendering the HTML. And without seeing your code, I don't think any more help is possible.

Comment: The valid answer even after years, but you should note that the `action` attribute that needs to be changed will be for the `<form>`, not for the `<button`.

Answer (score 60):

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='this.form.action="somethingelse";' />
```

Or you can modify it from outside the form, with javascript the normal way:

```
 document.getElementById('form_id').action = 'somethingelse';
```

Comment: This is a nice concise example. Beware though that if you have validation that takes place on form submission, and if that validation fails after clicking this button, then clicking a different submit button may still invoke the newly set action.

Comment: is there a way i could set the form action to be equal to an option select, within the form?

Answer (score 35):

There's a simple way to do this if you only need to support modern browsers: on your submit button, add a `formaction="/alternate/submit/url"` attribute like so:

```
<form>
    [fields]
    <input type="submit" value="Submit to a" formaction="/submit/a">
    <input type="submit" value="submit to b" formaction="/submit/b">
</form>
```

It also works on `<button>` tags.

The gotcha is that old versions of IE (<10) and the Android Browser (<4.0) do not support it. So, if you need to support older browsers, then the existing JS answers will probably work better for you.

More info: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly and support is wide enough.

Answer (score 23):

You can also set `onSubmit` attribute's value in form tag. You can set its value using Javascript.

Something like this:

```
<form id="whatever" name="whatever" onSubmit="return xyz();">
    Here is your entire form
    <input type="submit">
</form>;

<script type=text/javascript>
function xyz() {
  document.getElementById('whatever').action = 'whatever you want'
}
</script>
```

Remember that `onSubmit` has higher priority than action attribute. So whenever you specify `onSubmit` value, that operation will be performed first and then the form will move to action.

Comment: Bravo for using the more appropriate submit event, instead of click.

Comment: This should be the top answer. I usually submit forms by hitting `<enter>` not by clicking anywhere.

Comment: why use `onSubmit="return xyz();"` like this. can't we just have `onSubmit="xyz()"` ?

Comment: I completely for about the higher priority! That alone saved my as.. ahem, skin!

Answer (score 4):

You can do that on javascript side .

```
<input type="submit" value="Send It!" onClick="return ActionDeterminator();">
```

When clicked, the JavaScript function ActionDeterminator() determines the alternate action URL. Example code.

```
function ActionDeterminator() {
  if(document.myform.reason[0].checked == true) {
    document.myform.action = 'http://google.com';
  }
  if(document.myform.reason[1].checked == true) {
    document.myform.action = 'http://microsoft.com';
    document.myform.method = 'get';
  }
  if(document.myform.reason[2].checked == true) {
    document.myform.action = 'http://yahoo.com';
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5's *formaction* does not work on old IE browsers. An easy fix, based on some of the responses above, is:

```
<button onclick="this.form.action='/PropertiesList';" 
    Account Details </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```html
<form action="/home">
  
  <input type="submit" value="cancel">
  
  <input type="submit" value="login" formaction="/login">
  <input type="submit" value="signup" formaction="/signup">
  
</form>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.