# Edit formatting parameters passed by the URL CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a form with a single field, na `input type = "text"` when the form is submitted an **URL** is as follows:

> **`http://localhost:8765/products/search?search=notebook`**

I wish it gets up in the following way when subjected to the form:

> **`http://localhost:8765/products/search/notebook`**

Typing the **URL** up manually it works perfectly (I created a method that is able to get the contents after 
**search/**, also created a route specifies to have a **URL** above).

**Route Code (routes.php):**

```
$routes->connect('/products/search/:search', ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'search'], 
[':search' => '\w+', 'pass' => ['search']]);
```

**ProductsController.php Code (method responsible for action search)**

```
public function search($search) 
{ 
if($this->request->is('get')) 
{ 
//$product = $this->request->params['pass']; 
$this->paginate = [ 
'fields' => ['product_name', 'quantity', 'sold', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'thumbnail'], 
'conditions' => ['product_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'], 
'order' => ['price' => 'DESC'], 
'limit' => 3 
]; 

$this->set('products', $this->paginate($this->Products)); 
} 
}
```

**form Code:**

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'search'], 'type' => 'get', 'id' => 'search-form', 'class' => 'navbar-form span7 text-center']) ?> 
<button class="btn btn-info" title="Favorite o Site"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> 
</button> 
<?= $this->Form->text('search', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search']) ?> 
<?= $this->Form->button('Buscar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?> 
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**OBS1:** I imagine that the change should be made in this `form` (Just a guess).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a form's action attribute when submitting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640916/set-a-forms-action-attribute-when-submitting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two basic solutions

### Use Js

You can use js to change the url the form submits to:

```
<form 
    method="GET" 
    action="/base/url/" 
    onsubmit="document.location=this.action+document.getElementById('search-input-id').value; return false;"
>
  <input id="search-input" />
</form>
```

This is very simple and has no server side logic.

## Use Post-Redirect-Get

Alternatively, submit the form via post, and redirect the user to the appropriate url to see the results (A pattern known as [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).

E.g.:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="search-input" id="search-input" />
</form>
```

With an appropriate controller action:

```
public function search($search = null) 
{
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $term = $this->request->data['search-item'];
        // Any verification/validation/logic required
        // Redirect to same controller action with this search term
        return $this->redirect([$term]); 
    }
    ...
    // GET request, with $search term
```

The advantage of this technique is having a means to control/verify/validate the search term is valid before sending the user to the results page url.

Comment: Ok, I will apply and go back to talking if it worked

Comment: I'm using the first solution it worked but is being added to the end of the url querystring modified by getting javascript like this: `localhost:8765/products/search/notebook?search=notebook`@AD7six

Answer (score 2):

I used the `jQuery` lib to when the `form` is submitted suppress the default behavior, create a new url and make the redirection:

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // suppress default behavior
    action = $(this).attr('action') + '/' + document.getElementById('search').value; // create a new urldesejado
    window.location.href = action; //make the redirection
});
```