# Javascript - Input button won't work in Android, everything else works

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form. In this form there is an input area. When the user selects the input they are taken to one of three places depending on which device they are using. android - google play store, iphone - itunes store, desktop - itunes web browser. I am able to retrieve the iphone and desktop states, however Android doesn't seem to work on the form tag with an action attribute. The links work fine. Not sure what the issue is. Summary -- when I click the input button, nothing happens, no pop ups, nothing on my android. Also when I place the url of http://www.google.com into the action attribute of form it works correctly. Something is happening in between.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
<div class='main'>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<form id="store-link"  >
    <input type='submit'  value='Download'/>        
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
<p>footer</p>

</div>
</body>
<script>

 var a = document.getElementById('store-link'); 
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
 a.action = 'http://www.google.com';
 }
 if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||    (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
 a.action = 'itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peanuts-storygif-christmas/id1181016912?mt=8';
 }
else {
a.action = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peanuts-storygif-christmas/id1181016912?mt=8';
 }

</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: It seems that you can't change the action attribute on submit, [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640916/set-a-forms-action-attribute-when-submitting)

Answer (score 0):

Try ..

```
<form id="store-link"  >
    <input type='submit'  value='Download' onclick="action()" />        
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function action() {
var a = document.getElementById('store-link'); 
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
 a.setAttribute('action','http://www.google.com');
 }
 if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||    (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
 a.setAttribute('action,'itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peanuts-storygif-christmas/id1181016912?mt=8');
 }
else {
a.setAttribute('action','https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peanuts-storygif-christmas/id1181016912?mt=8');
 }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting console errors - Uncaught TypeError: action is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: you can use `jquery`.

Comment: That's not an option

Comment: use `javascript's setAttribute()` as above.

Comment: I got rid of the console error by just changing the name of the function but I am still getting the same result, nothing happens when I click the input button.