# HTML Form Action link change dynamically on radio selection

Tags: javascript, html

When I hit the submit button, I want to be able to "get" the input values (productID & styleID) and also be able to redirect to the page depending on which radio button selection I chose.

I've tried this so far and its getting the my input values correctly into the URL parameter but the action link is not dynamically changing to my selection as I do not know how. As you can see, I want for example the value="999" to replace "VALUE OF RADIO"  in my action link so that the link will look like this `http://test.ascension.systems/product/999/?productid=2095&styleid=888`

```
<form action="http://test.ascension.systems/product/<VALUE OF RADIO>/" method="get">
<input name="productid" type="hidden"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="third-row"><input id="1" class="input-hidden" name="styleid" type="radio" value="999" />1</input>
  <div class="third-row"><input id="2" class="input-hidden" name="styleid" type="radio" value="888" />2</input>
  <div class="third-row"><input id="3" class="input-hidden" name="styleid" type="radio" value="777" />3</input>
</div>
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Book an Appointment Now!" />
</form>
```

Comment: If the form is already rendered whenever you click submit, and the value is coming from a user action, the only method I could think is to invoke the `submit` manually on jquery and append that param to the url. Either that, or you could also change your paradigm to be something more MVVM like knockout or angular that supports 2 way binding. Believe me, first option could be simplier...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a form's action attribute when submitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640916/set-a-forms-action-attribute-when-submitting), in particular check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640946/2555516)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, looking at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users have suggested,

Here is a quick example of what you could do for now :

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="#" method="get">
    <p id="demo" value = "999" onclick ="myFunction('999')">Click me.</p>
  </form>
<script>
  function myFunction(clr) {
  console.log(clr);
  document.getElementById("myForm").action = 
  "http://test.ascension.systems/product/"+clr;

  console.log(document.getElementById("myForm").action);

//then do whatever you need to do 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But you might be better off with 2 way data binding in the future :) (as mentionned by @David Espino)

That would allow you do use something like :

```
<form id="myForm" action={{actionUrl}} method="get">
```

Here is a small jsbin to play around with 
https://jsbin.com/kezomejixo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I don't think this is going to help since the OP is wanting to know how to use the selected `radio` to set the action url. *"I want to be able to **get** the input values (productID & styleID) and also be able to redirect to the page **depending on** which radio button selection I chose"*

Comment: @NewToJS Its not exactly what I want but its helpful. Now for that issue, not sure how I am supposed to change "999" value depending on which is clicked. Perhaps throw in some logic conditions? not sure.

Comment: @pkmangg I think this is closer to what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/673k61rd/ Open the browser console to see the full url.

Comment: @NewToJS: you are right, answer could be better ;) working on it to improve (just edited it now), still looking at it to see how I could improve

And to pkmangg:  i am glad it still helps, you can check the new version :) maybe it'll make it easier

Comment: @Rose Take a look at my example if that helps. That actually gets the selected radio elements value to be used in the url rather than passing a static value/argument in the function call.

Comment: @pkmangg: you should definitely go for NewToJS's fiddle ;) much better than my answer ;) haha :) have a great day !

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks! But is there a way to also add the URL parameter for the "productid" input like this "http://test.ascension.systems/product/999/?productid=2095"

Comment: @pkmangg will the product ID be a match of the elements `id`? I'm assuming it would be, if so you could set a hidden input and give set the name attribute to `productid` and set the value when you set the form url... that would be one way of having the form submit that within the query. **Example** https://jsfiddle.net/673k61rd/1/ Remember to use the browser console to see the URL as jsfiddle cannot post to that url.